# Maximum of $\sum_{t = 0}^s \binom{m}{t} p^t (1-p)^{m-t}$?

Tags: functions, optimization

Let $p \in (\epsilon, 1]$ where $\epsilon > 0$. Then for some natural $m,s$ s.t $s < \frac{m}{2}$, let
$$f(p) = \sum_{t = 0}^s \binom{m}{t} p^t (1-p)^{m-t}  $$

Then is the maximum of $f$ at $p = \epsilon$?

I tried to show that $\frac{d}{dp} f(p) < 0$, but all the terms in the remaining summation are not negative and got stuck there. I even observed that $\sum_{t = 0}^s \binom{s}{t} p^t (1-p)^{m-t} = (1 - p)^{m-s}$, which is decreasing wrt p; additionally $f(p) = \sum_{t=0}^s \frac{\binom{m}{t}}{\binom{s}{t}} \cdot \Big( \binom{s}{t} p^t (1-p)^{m-t} \Big) $, but can't proceed from here.

I don't know if the result is true or if I have misinterpreted something from the paper I am reading. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove $f'(p)\lt 0$, one can use the idea of telescoping sum.

$$\small\begin{align}f'(p)&=-m(1-p)^{m-1}+\sum_{t=\color{red}1}^{s}\bigg(\binom mttp^{t-1}(1-p)^{m-t}-\binom mtp^t(m-t)(1-p)^{m-t-1}\bigg)
\\\\&=-m(1-p)^{m-1}+\sum_{t =1}^s \bigg(m\binom{m-1}{t-1}p^{t-1}(1-p)^{m-t}-\underbrace{m\binom{m-1}{t}p^t(1-p)^{m-t-1}}_{g(t)}\bigg)
\\\\&=-m(1-p)^{m-1}+\sum_{t = 1}^s \bigg(g(t-1)-g(t)\bigg)
\\\\&=-m(1-p)^{m-1}+g(0)-g(s)
\\\\&=-m(1-p)^{m-1}+m(1-p)^{m-1}-g(s)
\\\\&=-m\binom{m-1}{s}p^s(1-p)^{m-s-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: @DS : Oh, I see your point. I used $f$ in two meanings. Thanks.

Comment: (+1) makes sense now

Comment: I am almost sure that your interesting solution can be written in terms of double generatiing function like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1484579/305862).

Comment: @mathlove I think either this solution or I am, missing an important point: Nowhere does it use the fact that ($s < \frac{m}{2}$, if it does infact use this fact could you highlight where in the solution because I am not able see that) - so this implies that even for $s > \frac{m}{2}$, the function is decreasing and is maximized at $\epsilon$ - which kind of contradict's D S's intuitive answer below.

Comment: @Anon the derivative should be negative as long as $s<m$.

Comment: @D S Yes, as attested by the graphical representations I have given (I do not stop at $m/2$).

Comment: @D S Important : see the answer of @Wenxu [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4527672/305862) who gives a direct proof of the final expression $-m\binom{m-1}{s}p^s(1-p)^{m-s-1}$ of Anon (with different notations, of course) by connecting this issue to a Beta distribution. See as well [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/relationship-between-binomial-and-beta-distributions).

Comment: Besides using a Beta distribution (as indicated above), as I am still amazed by your so "compact" beautiful formula (but obtained by a non direct way...), I was thinking that you can consider the initial summation as the result of a repeated IPP (Integration By Parts ; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3358942/305862)) on this formula.

Answer (score 3):

To understand it more intuitively, consider the sum
$$\sum_{t = 0}^m \binom{m}{t} p^t (1-p)^{m-t}$$
which is equal to $1$ by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). Note that you can write the above sum in layman terms:
$$(1-p)^m + mp(1-p)^{m-1} + \frac{m(m-1)}{2} p^2 (1-p)^{m-2}+ \ldots+ \frac{m(m-1)}{2}p^{m-2}(1-p)^2 + mp^{m-1}(1-p) + p^m$$
However, $f(p)$ takes no more than half the terms of this sum. Since in the first half, the power of $(1-p)$ is greater than that of $p$, we must maximize $(1-p)$ if we want the maximum of $f$. That happens when $p$ is minimum, or when $p \to \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

For $X\sim \text{Binomial}(m,p)$, we have $f(p) = \mathbb{P}(X\le s)$. Making $p$ higher would decrease this probability. Consequently, $f(p)$ is decreasing in $p$.

Comment: Interesting, that's probably how the authors of the paper were able to state that result with no computation. But out of curiousity, how do you formally show "Making p higher would decrease this probability"?

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Mathlove's answer (and Wenxu answer, see my comment below), have a look at the following picture, where $m$ $f$ curves (we should write $f_{m,s}$ curves) have been plotted for $m=41$ and $s$ ranging from $0$ to $m$, the largest values of $s$ being rightmost, resulting in a symmetrical pattern..

Please note that I haven't stopped at integer part of $m/2$.

Please note their inverted "S" shapes, the name given to the curves of cumulative distribution functions.

[image]

Here is the Matlab program that I wrote for the  generation of these curves :

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;
 axis([0,1,0,1]);
 text(1,0.05,'p');
 m=41;
 for s=0:m; % m instead of floor(m/2)
    S=[];
    for p=0:0.02:1
       q=1-p;F=zeros(1,s+1);
       for t=0:s
          F(t+1)=nchoosek(m,t)*p^t*q^(m-t);
       end
       S=[S,sum(F)];
    end
    plot(0:0.02:1,S,'linewidth',5)
 end;
```